# Google cloud Datastore Kind unable to return all records when queried with WHERE clause ( 2 - 3 filters ) using Datastore java API's

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, gqlquery

My datastore Kind is indexed on 5 columns.

When I query the Kind with 3 indexed filters using java API's :

```
RunQueryRequest.Builder request = RunQueryRequest.newBuilder();
 request.setPartitionId(partitionId);
 GqlQuery gqlQuery= GqlQuery.newBuilder()
                     .setQueryString(query)
                     .setAllowLiterals(true)
                     .build();

 request.setGqlQuery(gqlQuery);
 return datastore.runQuery(request.build());
```

And retrieved using :

`runQueryResponse.getBatch().getEntityResultsList();`

method returns only 1-2 records but when queried from UI same query gives more than 1000 records.

depedencies used :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.datastore</groupId>
        <artifactId>datastore-v1-protos</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.datastore</groupId>
        <artifactId>datastore-v1-proto-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Please, provide query itself.

Comment: Query : `SELECT * FROM _Kind_ where _col1_="string" and _col2_=0 and _col3_="string" LIMIT 10000`

Answer (score 0):

resolved by adding datastore API's latest version dependency (Mar 5'18)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And used it's methods to create GQLQuery object

```
GqlQuery<Entity> gqlQuery = Query.newGqlQueryBuilder(Query.ResultType.ENTITY, query)
                     .setNamespace("nameSpace").setAllowLiteral(true).build();
```

to pass it to

```
datastore.run(gqlQuery)
```